# Is replication of a couchdb document with attachments atomic?

Tags: couchdb, attachment, atomic, database-replication

When a couchdb document with attachments is replicated, is that replication an atomic operation or is there a short timeframe in which the document does not yet have its attachments?

Answer (score 0):

The replication of an individual document including its attachments is an atomic operation.

Source: What rnewson said on Freenode.